# Java - Number of connections being hold by C3P0 dont match with the sleeping ones in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0

Well, here is the scenario:

I'm using Java and I have a centralized class to connect and disconnect to the database. I've set the maximum pool size for my ComboPooledDataSource to 30 (`cpds.setMaxPoolSize(30)`), for no special reasons. MySQL has the `time_wait` configuration set to 100 seconts.

My problem:

When running my program and comparing its logs with the ones being generated in MySQL I can clearly see that MySQL is doing what it was supposed to do: closing sleeping connections after 100 secs (the very ones created by my program). But the same connections being closed in MySQL seems to be still alive in my C3P0 Connection Pool, as the number of connections only grows up (I test it everytime a new connection is required with `cpds.getNumConnections()`).

There's any way to clean up unused connections (the ones that were closed in MySQL) back in c3p0? Because my max number of connections is being reached soon (200s - 300s). Connections closed by MySQL are not automatically closed in c3p0?

Answer (score 3):

C3P0 offers a number of timeout parameters. Please check their documentation for details: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#basic_pool_configuration

Particularly the section about "Managing Pool Size and Connection Age" will be of interest to you. Here're some of the settings that you can tweak: maxConnectionAge, maxIdleTime, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a `time_wait` parameter. `time_wait` is a state of a TCP connection.

If you are setting `wait_timeout` to 100 (overriding its default of 28800), you are asking for trouble. The whole point of a Connection pool like c3p0 is to keep Connections open so that they can be reused.

c3p0 can detect and observe when Connections have been closed out from underneath it by the DBMS via Connection testing. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

If you really want your MySQL to kill your Connections after 100 secs, and you want c3p0 to notice that, you can set c3p0's `idleConnectionTestPeriod` to something like 30, and c3p0 will quickly detect and dispose of dead Connections. But then when the number of Connections falls below `minPoolSize`, it will recreate the dead Connection, and your application will churn uselessly. A much better approach is to leave MySQL's `wait_timeout` large, and control the number of open Connections with `maxPoolSize`.

(You'll still want to configure some form of Connection testing though, almost always.)